# About the martingale.

Tags: martingales

For martingale, we have $E[X_{n+1}-EX_n|X_1,\dots,X_n]=0$, can we say $X_{n+1}-X_n$ is independent of $X_1,\dots,X_n$?

Comment: On this site, the traditional prefix for obviously wrong statements is "I know that...". In reality, $X_n$ being a martingale means $E[X_{n+1}-X_n|X_1,\dots,X_n]=0$. And no, that doesn't mean independence.

Comment: Could you please give an example of this?

Comment: $X_{n+1}=X_n\,(1+Y_n)$, where $Y_n$ is independent of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $P(Y_n=1)=P(Y_n=-1)=\frac12$.